# Regarding vector operator

Tags: matrices, vectors, tensor-products, tensors

In my research work, I came across the following statement of vector operator: " operator vec(.) vectorizes $I \times J$ matrix argument".

Also, the following expression contains the vec(.) operator:

$\mathbf{Y}_3 = [\text{vec}(\mathbf{Y}[1]),...,\text{vec}(\mathbf{Y}[K])]^T$ ---(1)

where $T$ denotes Transpose, $k$ ranges from $1...K$ and dimension of $\mathbf{Y}[k]$ is $L \times T$.

My query is I am not getting what exactly vec(.) operator is performing its role in equation (1).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))?

Comment: Ok...Thank u so much sir for your response....